# Flutter how to create boolean field in mapped Struct using FFIGen

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I'm trying to using latest FFIGEN (11.0.0) and almost latest Flutter 3.16.4 (dart 3.2.3)

This my my struct in C++

```cpp
struct TestStruct {
    const char *name;
    bool isOnline;
    uint8_t batteryLevel;
    uint32_t timestamp;
};
```

And this is exported using

```cpp
extern "C" struct TestStruct;
```

The problem is that every time I run FFIGEN it generates

```dart
final class TestStruct extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> name;

  @ffi.Int()
  external int isOnline;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int batteryLevel;

  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int timestamp;
}
```

I have to manually change boolean entry to:

```dart
  @ffi.Bool()
  external bool isOnline;
```

I even tried to leave it and map int to bool later, but dart object is not correct.

Any ideas how to make ffigen understand bool field?

Comment: What platform are you on? I’m having the same issue on Linux (Fedora), but my Mac correctly treats it as a bool.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and looking at the output there was a problem with a header file not being found. I added this line to my `.bashrc` file:

`export CPATH="$(clang -v 2>&1 | grep "Selected GCC installation" | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev)/include"`

Now the error is gone and booleans are properly generated.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/native/issues/338) was useful.

Comment: Thank you, in the end it was issue with missing headers, but it was not visible. After adding stdbool.h include it now generates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this issue was to include `#include <stdbool.h>` in this file.
Even though everything worked from C++ code, dart was not aware of bool type.